# Showing a div on hover and enabling a selection of the content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I am using the [`hoverIntent.js`](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) jQuery plugin to enable a `div` be made visible on hover which I have managed to successfully achieve.

The problem I am now trying to solve is to enable items within this now visible `div` to be selected. I guess I would like to pass this hovered intent over to this now visible `div`. Is this possible and how would I go about doing this?

[Here is an example of my problem on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taJmz/3/)

**Update**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/taJmz/5/) is an update to the problem - basically there is more then one div floated beside each other launching a separate hidden div.

Answer (score 1):

If you nest your elements withing the `inner-block` you will get the desired effect

```
<div class="block">    
    <div class="inner-block">
        <h1>Button</h1>
        <div id="hide">
            <h2>Blah</h2>
            <h2>Blah</h2>
            <h2>Blah</h2>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hide").hide();
    $(".inner-block").hoverIntent({
        over: show,
        timeout: 100,
        out: hide
    });

});

function show() {
    $("#hide").show("fast");
};

function hide() {
    $("#hide").hide("slow");
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/taJmz/4/

Comment: Thanks for your post. However this is not the desired behaviour that I am looking at. I have added an updated example which I hope will explain my problem better.

Comment: I might have to change the way I am thinking about this problem and construct the markup better.